# Failed to run amd64 docker image on Oracle arm64 VPS

Tags: docker, docker-compose, x86-64, arm64, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

My docker compose config yml file is below

```
version: '3'

services:
  elasticsearch:
    platform: linux/amd64
    image: elasticsearch:1.4.5
    command: elasticsearch -Des.network.host=0.0.0.0
    ports:
      - "127.0.0.1:9200:9200"
      - "127.0.0.1:9300:9300"
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - elasticsearch-data:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
volumes:
  elasticsearch-data: {}
```

I am trying to run it at my free oracle `arm64` vps but failed.
The error is `exec /docker-entrypoint.sh: exec format error`

Someone said `platform: linux/amd64` should make a AMD64 based docker image running on arm64 computer. But it does not work for me.

How to make it work?

Comment: Why not run the arm64-version?

Comment: @kometen Good question. We have some code based on old version elasticsearch. We cannot upgrade/change docker image without changing our code. That's a lot of extra work for us. Is there a way to run amd64 image on oracle arm64 vps?

Comment: Then I would use a amd64 VPS instead. To run amd64 binaries on arm64 you need a layer that translate the amd64 instructions to arm64 ditto like Apple provides with their Rosetta2 for their Mx-chipset.

Comment: try https://serverfault.com or https://superuser.com if the question is closed here